# Should I rely on AJAX or trust JavaScript for Markdown

Tags: javascript, python, markdown

I'm working on a little addon to one of my larger projects wherein when a user types some text in a textarea (somewhat similar to StackOverflow) the text is then parsed and returned in Markdown format. I think it'll help make the UI a little bit more snappy and look simpler.

I'm struggling between using AJAX and after every space that's typed send a request to return the parsed data through my current Python Markdown parser or use a built-in JavaScript parser.

I'm using Python for the entire project and I'm worried they'll be small differences between the two that I probably won't notice now but will find later on.

Will relying on AJAX for the parsing be suitable or should I trust the JavaScript implementation for *display* and then parse it through Python afterwards for storing the data?

I'm looking at [this](https://github.com/chjj/marked) for JavaScript and currently using [this](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/) for Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Since Markdown is a set of rules, they should both work together nicely. In case you didn't read these : [Python-Markdown's differences](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/#differences) and [marked's philosy](). After that I think you should feel confident. Another thing you can do is run test suits on both (this might require porting on your side) and see if they have different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Marked (although at a quick glance it looks pretty nice), but Python-Markdown has a pretty extensive [test suite](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/tree/master/tests). Run through those tests with Marked and you should have a pretty good idea how well their behavior matches up. In fact, this is a pretty good way to compare any two markdown implementations (see [Babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/) for a comparison of many implementations and check the [FAQ](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/faq.html#what-are-some-examples-of-interesting-divergences-between-implementations) for a list of known pain points).

Python-Markdown's test suite is comprised mostly of matching text and html files. The test suite simply walks through those files, runs the text files through the markdown parser and compares the output with the html file. If there are any differences the test fails. The php and perl implementations use the same method of testing and in fact Python-Markdown runs those tests as well.

There is one gotcha with using another implementation's tests. Every implementation seems to output insignificant whitespace in the html a little different. So you need to normalize the whitespace before comparing. As you are testing a JavaScript implementation, that should be pretty easy to do.